# Azure Data Factory Parameter / Extended Property value leading special character issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Data Factory parameter value starting with [ (square bracket) causing issue publishing to Data Factory from Master branch. I have added some parameters for our Azure Analysis Services processing to help streamline the deployment between environments and one of the values is a client secret that starts with a leading square bracket. This works fine when working on the pipeline in a branch or deploying to master branch, but when we publish it to the actual Data Factory it adds an extra square bracket in the value. I tried to update it directly in the Data Factory and publish, but same thing. How can we resolve this and get this bug resolved? I also see that this is an issue with our Extended Property values in Custom Activities.

So in the screenshot this parameter value should only have one square bracket at the beginning:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with a pipeline parameter and cannot reproduce your error. Try reading the Json code, maybe that gives you a clue.

How are you loading your parameters? Maybe its an issue with the way or code you are using to create the pipelines.

Hope this helped!

Comment: i am putting a string value in the parameters and works fine in a Git branch (even Master), but now in the actual Data Factory it doesn't accept that and adds extra square bracket. Very easy to reproduce and it behaves the same for our Custom Activity Extended Property values as well. I just tried doing it again to see if anything changed and still behaves the same. I am going to open an Azure ticket for this bug. I believe it was working fine last week and someone else in the Yammer Advisors Data Factory stated the same thing.

Comment: If anyone from Microsoft is able to look into this issue with Data Factory publishing I have created an Azure support ticket with the following # 119051524001596 . Thanks.

Comment: Now I see what you mean, you create a pipeline within a github and works well, but when checking the same pipeline in data factory, it adds an extra [. Its probably a bug. As a workaround, maybe you can add it with data factory functions?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions I recommend concat

Answer (score 0):

This is the current workaround until the bug is resolved by the ADF team and I have tested this and it works.

Please find below update from PG and let me know the work around status.

There's already a work item created for this bug.
As a workaround, you can turn this feature off until the bug is fixed.
1. Append this to your URL: &feature.escapeBracket=false
2. Refresh the page with the new URL
3. Remove the extra bracket from the pipeline parameter value
4. publish your changes
5. Refresh page to verify everything is back to normal

Please let me know if you have any questions/concerns on this issue.